# Generate date_range for string intervals like 09:00-10:00/11:00-14:00/15:00-18:00 and calculate the working minutes

Tags: python, performance, datetime, pandas

I'm a bit new in python and I'm trying to achieve what I can't with VBA, get things faster.

I have large datasets like this in the source(just a sample):
[image: Sample data]

This is done also by python and it's a CSV file.

What my code has to do with this is:

1. Get the column "Planned" And "Department Planned".
2. Convert the schedules in "Planned" column to 30 min intervals between starting and ending. Some schedules can be weird like 09:37-15:42 (so they need to be handled, normalizing the intervals from 9:30 to 15:30)
3. With that list, calculate the minutes worked in another column refering to the original schedule, so in the example 09:37 will have an interval starting from 9:30 but there will be only 23 mins working there.
4. explode the columns from points 2 and 3 to rows repeating the column Department Planned and Location NAme.
5. Group by: Location Name, Date Time (from point 3), Department Planned. Adding the minutes worked.

This is the code:

```
#calcula_Presentes_Contratados
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def configuraDataFrame(df, horario, modo):
    #drop unwanted columns and filter empty rows
    df = df[df.columns.intersection([
                                        'CentroPlanificacion', 
                                        'Fecha',
                                        horario,
                                        modo
                                        ])]
    df = df[df[horario].notna()]
    if df.empty:
        return df       
    return df[df[horario].str.contains(":")]
def fechaYHora(horario, fecha, posicion):
    #calculate time and date for each start and ending time if the ending time < starting time, add one day to the ending.
    hora = datetime.strptime(horario.split('-')[posicion], '%H:%M')
    fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if posicion == 1: 
        horaI = datetime.strptime(horario.split('-')[0], '%H:%M')
        horaI = datetime(fecha.year, fecha.month, fecha.day, horaI.hour, 0)
    if hora.minute >= 30:
        hora = datetime(fecha.year, fecha.month, fecha.day, hora.hour, 30)
    else:
        hora = datetime(fecha.year, fecha.month, fecha.day, hora.hour, 0)
    if posicion == 1 and hora < horaI: hora += timedelta(days=1)
    return hora
def extraeRangos(horario, fecha, aplicaSeparador):
    try:
        #get all match schedules if there are any
        partido = horario.split('/')
        listahorarios = []        
        #loop through al the schedules and add the range with the split separator "Separa aquí"
        for horarios in partido:
            rangoactual = pd.date_range(start=fechaYHora(horarios, fecha, 0), end=fechaYHora(horarios, fecha, 1), freq="30min").strftime('%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M').to_list()        
            listahorarios += rangoactual
            if aplicaSeparador: listahorarios.append('Separa aquí')  
        return listahorarios
    except:
        return
def calculaMinutosInicio(horaInicio, tramoInicial):
    #function to calculate starting minutes
    horaInicio = datetime.strptime(horaInicio,'%H:%M')
    tramoFin = datetime.strptime(tramoInicial.split(", ")[1], '%H:%M') + timedelta(minutes=30)
    if tramoFin < horaInicio: horaFin += timedelta(days=1)
    return tramoFin - horaInicio
def calculaMinutosFin(horaFin, tramoFin):
    #function to calculate ending minutes
    horaFin = datetime.strptime(horaFin,'%H:%M')
    if horaFin.minute == 0 or horaFin.minute == 30: return timedelta(seconds=0)
    tramoFin = datetime.strptime(tramoFin.split(", ")[1], '%H:%M')
    return horaFin - tramoFin
def generaListasPorPartido(lista_tramos):
    lista_final = []
    listaTemp = []
    #loop through the list looking for "Separa aquí"
    for tramo in lista_tramos:
        #if found, all the items stored before in the list will go in a single list
        if tramo == 'Separa aquí':
            lista_final.append(listaTemp)
            listaTemp = []
        #store all items in between "Separa aquí"
        else:
            listaTemp.append(tramo)
    #return a list of lists for each matching schedule
    return lista_final
def generaListaTramos(lista_tramos, horario):
    listatramos = []
    #calculate starting minutes from starting time to starting interval
    minutosInicio = int(calculaMinutosInicio(horario.split("-")[0], lista_tramos[0]).seconds / 60)
    #calculate ending minutes from ending time to ending interval
    minutosFin = int(calculaMinutosFin(horario.split("-")[1], lista_tramos[-1]).seconds / 60)
    for tramo in lista_tramos:
        #the first index will have the starting minutes
        if lista_tramos.index(tramo) == 0:
            listatramos.append(minutosInicio)
        #the last index will have the ending minutes
        elif tramo == lista_tramos[-1]:
            listatramos.append(minutosFin)
        #every interval in between will always have 30 minutes
        else:
            listatramos.append(30)
    return listatramos
def calculaConexion(lista_tramos, horario):
    #if the list is not empty
    if len(lista_tramos) > 0:
        listatramos = []      
        #gnerate a list for each match schedule
        lista_tramos = generaListasPorPartido(lista_tramos)
        horario: horario = horario.split("/")
        #add the working minutes to each interval
        for i in range(len(lista_tramos)):
            listatramos.extend(generaListaTramos(lista_tramos[i], horario[i]))      
        return listatramos
def eliminaSeparadores(lista):    
    return list(filter(('Separa aquí').__ne__, lista))
def generaRangoHoras(df, campo, nuevo_campo):
    #generate range of times column
    df[nuevo_campo] = df.apply(lambda row: extraeRangos(row[campo], row['Fecha'], True), axis=1)
    #generate working minutes column
    df['Conexión_' + nuevo_campo] = df.apply(lambda row: calculaConexion(row[nuevo_campo], row[campo]), axis=1)
    #get rid of the manual separator for match schedules
    df[nuevo_campo] = df.apply(lambda row: eliminaSeparadores(row[nuevo_campo]), axis=1)
    return df
def explotaHoras(df, listaSinExplotar):
    df = df.set_index(listaSinExplotar).apply(pd.Series.explode).fillna('').reset_index()
    return df
def main(rutaficheros):
    #read soruce file
    rutaExcel = rutaficheros + 'BaseACC.csv'
    dfOrigen = pd.read_csv(rutaExcel, converters={i: str for i in range(100)}) 
    #create lists to loop   
    listaCamposHorario = ['Programado', 'Programado 2']
    listaCamposModo = ['Modo Planificado', 'Modo Planificado 2']
    #for each item in list, create the time range, working minutes and export the file
    for horario, modo in zip(listaCamposHorario, listaCamposModo):
        df = configuraDataFrame(dfOrigen, horario, modo)
        if not df.empty:
            df = generaRangoHoras(df, horario, 'Franjas_Programado')
            df = explotaHoras(df, ['CentroPlanificacion', 'Fecha', horario, modo])
            #drop unwanted columns for the final result
            df = df.drop([horario, 'Fecha'], axis=1)
            #drop unwanted rows for the final result
            df = df[df['Conexión_Franjas_Programado'] > 0]
            #group all the working minutes by location, planned/planned2 and department/department2
            df = df.groupby(['CentroPlanificacion', modo, 'Franjas_Programado']).agg({'Conexión_Franjas_Programado' : 'sum'}).reset_index()
            df.to_csv(rutaficheros + horario + '.csv', index=False)
    return
```

And this should be the output:

[image: Output files]

The output file:

[image: Output file]

This takes around 35 seconds when I have a 100k rows source file and I think it could be better but I'm still very new in python to know more efficient ways to code.

### Sample data

```
Dirección,Territorio,DNI,Agente,CentroPlanificacion,Campaña Origen,Fecha,Presentes,Contratados,ModoPlanificacion,Habilidades Agente,Programado,Modo Planificado,Programado 2,Modo Planificado 2
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-01,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-02,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-13:00,Department1,13:00-15:00,Department2
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-03,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-10:00/11:00-14:00/15:00-18:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-04,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,22:00-06:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-05,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-06,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-07,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-08,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-09,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-10,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-11,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-12,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-13,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-14,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-15,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-16,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-17,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-18,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-19,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-20,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-21,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-22,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-23,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-24,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-25,VAC,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,VAC,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-26,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-27,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-28,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-29,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-30,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-31,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
```

Comment: Does `calculaMinutosInicio` work? It refers to a `horaFin` that is not defined in scope.

Comment: @Reinderien I've uploaded to my github the same sample I'm using thought changing everything (not important) so there is no problem. Also the `horaFin` is wrong, shoudl be `tramoFin`

Comment: @Reinderien now I've pasted the raw data from a CSV file. Should work pasting this to a CSV back.

Comment: It took a while, but we got there.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight I think now it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider revamping your current setup to work mostly in Pandas methods that operates on whole DataFrames and Series objects as opposed to mostly built-in Python methods on scalar values that loop and append to lists.

Beginners should know Pandas/Numpy programming is markedly different than general purpose Python programming. Below is working solution for one shift column on sample data. Of course, adjust and expand as needed to meet actual, larger data.

**Input**

*For demonstration, I changed the shift start of very first record to 9:37 and shift end of very last record to 13:37.*

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''Dirección,Territorio,DNI,Agente,CentroPlanificacion,Campaña Origen,Fecha,Presentes,Contratados,ModoPlanificacion,Habilidades Agente,Programado,Modo Planificado,Programado 2,Modo Planificado 2
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-01,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-02,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:37-13:00,Department1,13:00-15:00,Department2
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-03,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-04,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-05,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-06,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-07,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-08,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-09,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-10,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-11,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-12,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-13,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-14,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-15,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-16,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-17,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-18,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-19,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-20,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-21,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-22,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-23,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-24,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-25,VAC,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,VAC,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-26,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-27,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-28,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-29,LIBRE,LIBRE,Department1,Department1,LIBRE,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-30,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-15:00,Department1,,
BussinessName,TerritoryNAme,WorkerID1,WorkerName1,Location1,Department1,2022-05-31,09:00-15:00,09:00-15:00,Department1,Department1,09:00-13:37,Department1,,'''

with StringIO(txt) as f:
    raw_df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

**Cleaning**

*See [**`Series.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), [**`Series.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [**`Series.str.cat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html), [**`pandas.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), and [**`pandas.notnull`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notnull.html).*

```py
# SUBSET COLUMNS
raw_df = raw_df[
    ["Territorio", "Campaña Origen", "Fecha", "Programado", "Modo Planificado"]
]

# SPLIT SHIFT RANGE
raw_df[["Shift_Start", "Shift_End"]] = (
    raw_df["Programado"].replace({"LIBRE": None, "VAC": None})
       .str.split("-", 1, expand=True)
)

# CONCATENATE DAY AND TIME, THEN CONVERT TO DATETIME
raw_df["Shift_Start"], raw_df["Shift_End"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(raw_df["Fecha"].str.cat(raw_df["Shift_Start"], sep= " ")),
    pd.to_datetime(raw_df["Fecha"].str.cat(raw_df["Shift_End"], sep=" "))
)

# REMOVE FREE DAYS
raw_df = raw_df[
    pd.notnull(raw_df["Shift_Start"]) & pd.notnull(raw_df["Shift_End"])
]
```

**Expanding Rows**

*See [**`pandas.date_range`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), [**`pandas.Timestamp.floor`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html), [**`pandas.Timedelta`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), [**`DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [**`DataFrame.iterrows`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), and [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).*

```py
def expand_row_by_dates(row):
    # BUILD RANGE FROM START TO END IN 30 MIN INTERVALS
    shift_range = pd.date_range(
        row["Shift_Start"].floor('30min'),
        row["Shift_End"].floor('30min'), 
        freq='30min'
    )

    # BUILD NEW LONGER DATA FRAME, BINDING ROW VALUES AND DATE RANGE
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Territorio": row["Territorio"], 
        "Campaña Origen": row["Campaña Origen"], 
        "Fecha": row["Fecha"],
        "Shift_Date": shift_range,
        "Minutes_Worked": 30
    })
    
    # RE-CALCULATE FIRST 30 MIN INTERVAL TO ACTUAL
    diff = (
        (row["Shift_Start"] - df["Shift_Date"].min()) / 
        pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
    )
    df.loc[df.index[0], "Minutes_Worked"] = (30-diff) if diff != 0 else 30)    
        
    # RE-CALCULATE LAST 30 MIN INTERVAL TO ACTUAL
    diff = (
        (row["Shift_End"] - df["Shift_Date"].max()) / 
        pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
    )
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Minutes_Worked"] = (diff if diff != 0 else 30)
    
    return df

# ITERATE THROUGH ROWS AND COMPILE EXPANDED DATA FRAMES
shifts_df = pd.concat(
    [expand_row_by_dates(row) for i, row in raw_df.iterrows()],
    ignore_index=True
)
```

**Output**

```py
shifts_df

        Territorio Campaña Origen       Fecha          Shift_Date  Minutes_Worked
0    TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-02 2022-05-02 09:30:00              23
1    TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-02 2022-05-02 10:00:00              30
2    TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-02 2022-05-02 10:30:00              30
3    TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-02 2022-05-02 11:00:00              30
4    TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-02 2022-05-02 11:30:00              30
..             ...            ...         ...                 ...             ...
260  TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-31 2022-05-31 11:30:00              30
261  TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-31 2022-05-31 12:00:00              30
262  TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-31 2022-05-31 12:30:00              30
263  TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-31 2022-05-31 13:00:00              30
264  TerritoryNAme    Department1  2022-05-31 2022-05-31 13:30:00               7
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait, will give this a try and report back!

Comment: Wonderful approach! Just had to tweak a little thing things. where you recalculate the last interval. If someone has 9:00-15:00 for example, at 15:00 their working minutes are 0 so should be like this `df.loc[df.index[-1], "Minutes_Worked"] = (diff if diff != 0 else 0)`

Comment: Funny thing though, this code takes twice as much... Maybe isn't that efficient with large datasets? The sample is only 30 rows, but the sample data is around 100k Parfait.

Comment: Hmmmm...Only explicit loop is `iterrows`. Thinking now it is expanding shift duration in 30 min intervals for each of 100k days. See if `pands.concat` is bottleneck by just running the list comprehension with `iterrows`. Maybe `date_range` is a hidden loop. Might be a numpy alternative.

Comment: Parfait maybe it helps to know that your output is 441646 rows. Because your code only handles shifts with one start and end, so I had to add the splitting part for shifts with lunch time in between. I'm trying to frankenstein your code with mine.

Comment: Parfait thats the thing, not everyone has the same schedule. What I did to handle this was:     `raw_df['timeblocks']= raw_df.Programado.str.split('/')
    raw_df = raw_df.explode('timeblocks')` then work on that column instead 'Programado' thought this takes only 0.0005s so it can't be the reason to slow the code.  In your 'expand_row_by_dates` function I've also added this at the start: `if row["Shift_End"] < row["Shift_Start"]:
        row["Shift_End"] = pd.DateOffset(days=1) + row["Shift_End"]`so I could handle shifts ending on the next day.

Comment: Ok. Again, can you test if `concat` or function is issue by only running at the end: `shifts_list = [expand_row_by_dates(row) for i, row in raw_df.iterrows()]`? Test with and without your changes, restarting Python session each time. There may be a chance to use `reindex` and not `iterrows` Traveling now, will try in day or so.

Comment: Parfait it's totally the iteration... since you gotta iterate for almost 500k rows it slows down the process. Finally mixed our codes and got the same result, I'm trying now to use the best part of your code along with my less clean code which doesn't generate 500k rows, just a 10% of that.

Comment: Finally understood why, your code runs fast, mine does too but I had a flaw preventing pandas from reading the whole dataframe when yours was doing it fine.

Answer (score 2):

Things that are good to stay in Spanish: your starting input file, your final output file. Everything else - your variable names, function names, comments, parameter names, and the column names of your intermediate data-processing dataframes - should all be in English. You're halfway there already. For better or worse, English is the de-facto language of programming, and it's important that you be consistent for the purposes of international collaboration.

By PEP8 your comments `#` should have a space between the hash and the text. There are lots of other PEP8 issues that will be picked up if you (a) write this within a reasonable IDE like PyCharm, and (b) follow its recommendations. An important one: two blank lines between every function.

Also by PEP8, use lower_snake_case for function and variable names; i.e. `fechaYHora` would be `date_and_time` (better yet, `get_date_and_time` which is an action phrase).

You have some variable names - `listatramos` and `lista_tramos` - that only differ by underscore within the same scope. This is a deeply bad idea. Instead use perhaps `old_ranges` and `new_ranges` (if that's what these actually represent).

You need to decompose every single `df.apply` that you have into vectorised operations.  I don't think a single one of them needs to exist. Each of these needs to be replaced with a series of operations that operates on the whole dataframe at once. This is probably the source of most of your performance trouble.

Related: list-wise operations such as those in `generaListasPorPartido` also need to go away and be replaced with vectorised operations.

In `extraeRangos` your `try`/`except` needs to go away. If there are errors, either your code is wrong and you need to fix it, or there are edge cases in the data that you need to take care of explicitly.

Don't do this:

```
converters={i: str for i in range(100)}
```

Instead, load the dataframe with proper datetimes where they exist; basically:

```
parse_dates=['Fecha']
```

I encourage you to work on all of the above, and then once you're satisfied and ready for another round of review, come back to this site and post a new question with the new code.

Comment: That's the thing here Reinderien. I don't know how to change the `df.apply` into vectorised operations... I was looking here for some directions or possible replacement for the highest time consuming functions. About the code, will get everything you taught me here and replace everything. But if you could consider telling me how to change some logic that I have in UDF to vectorised operations... Would be so helpfull!

Comment: You need to do some self-guided research, particularly around the Pandas support for vectorised [string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) operations.